# How to redirect http to https://www.example.com using htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl-certificate

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I have created a website using `Codeigniter` framework and my domain and hosting is on `GoDaddy`. Now, I have installed `SSL certificate` and manage with my website. Now, when I use `example.com` in URL it redirects me on `https://www.example.com` but when I click on my `login` page it shows me `Not Found` and URL looks like `https://www.example.com/index.php?/login` but I want URL Like `https://www.example.com/login`. So, How can I do this? Please help.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change order of your rules
2. Have a single rule to redirect `www` and `http -> https`

Your .htaccess should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect for adding www and https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for your testing.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this htaccess rules will work 100%

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```